# error while creating adminclient for websphere 7.0.0.11

Tags: java, jmx, websphere-7, mbeans

I need to develop an application for managing WebSphere Application Server v7.0.0.11. I explored a bit and found out that we can use Mbeans. Actually I need to create something similar as Web-sphere's web console.

My problem is that the application should be in C# .net so is there any connector/Adapter to invoke web-sphere's management API. Please point me in right direction.

I am a C#.net developer and a total newbie in java/websphere, I tried creating Admin Client Example from IBM site by using packages found at IBM/Webshpere/Cimrepos directory. The name of Jar file is **`com.ibm.wplc.was_7.0.0.11.jar`** I unzipped that jar file in the same folder.

So now My App is starts, connects to websphere successfully and finds mbean on the nodeAgent. The problem I am facing in invoking mbean. I am getting following error message.

***`exception invoking launchProcess : javax.management.ReflectionExcetion: Target Method not found com.ibm.ws.management.nodeagent.NodeAgent.launchProcess`***

I am using following url for list of mbean

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/mbeanDocs/index.html

i tried using different methods from nodeAgent mbean but no joy , I am always getting same exception **"method not found"**.

Following is the code snipped for invoking launchprocess

```
private void invokeLaunchProcess(String serverName)  
    {  
        // Use the launchProcess operation on the NodeAgent MBean to start  
        // the given server  
        String opName = "launchProcess";  
        String signature[] = { "java.lang.String" };  
        String params[] = { serverName };  
        boolean launched = false;  
        try  
        {  
            Boolean b = (Boolean)adminClient.invoke(nodeAgent, opName, params, null);  
            launched = b.booleanValue();  
            if (launched)  
                System.out.println(serverName + " was launched");  
            else  
                System.out.println(serverName + " was not launched");  

        }  
        catch (Exception e)  
        {  
            System.out.println("Exception invoking launchProcess: " + e);  
        }  
    }
```

Full Code could be found on following link

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Ftjmx_develop.html

Please let me know what I am doing wrong, do i need to include some other package ? I browsed `com.ibm.wplc.was_7.0.0.11.jar`, there isn't any folder named nodeagent in `com\ibm\ws\managemnt`. I found the same jar file in Appserver\runtimes library.

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks in Advance.

**Getting Mbean**

```
private void getNodeAgentMBean(String nodeName)
    {
        // Query for the ObjectName of the NodeAgent MBean on the given node
        try
        {
            String query = "WebSphere:type=NodeAgent,node=" + nodeName + ",*";
            ObjectName queryName = new ObjectName(query);
            Set s = adminClient.queryNames(queryName, null);
            if (!s.isEmpty())
                nodeAgent = (ObjectName)s.iterator().next();
            else
            {
                System.out.println("Node agent MBean was not found");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }
        catch (MalformedObjectNameException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        catch (ConnectorException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(-1);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        System.out.println("Found NodeAgent MBean for node " + nodeName);
    }
```

Comment: Can you give the query you are using while getting the nodeagent and can you get a Sysout of the ObjectName (NodeAgent) and give the results?

Comment: thanks for replying adding the query for getting node agent. Added the code snippet for getting nodeAgentmbean

Comment: can you provide the result of system.out.println("NodeAgent : "+nodeAgent);

Comment: @sgpalit Follwoing is the result of system.out.println("Node Agent:" +nodeAgent)   ***Node Agent: WebSphere:name=NodeAgent,process=nodeagent,platform=common,node=node02,diagnosticProvider=true,version=7.0.0.11,type=NodeAgent,mbeanIdentifier=NodeAgent,Cell=MBcell_1,spec=1.0***

Comment: I have no solution but I can suggest some other way to check if it works. Can you try to run wsadmin tool and try to start the server from it? is your JDK, IBM JDK?

Comment: Since i am new to java I am not sure but i think i am using normal jdk ***(jdk version 1.7)*** and packages from **com.ibm.wplc.was_7.0.0.11.jar** I found this jar in Appserver\Runtimes directory. Thanks for helping me out.   I cant use wsadmin since i need to create a web application just like websphere's web console using api,since calling api function is more reliable then running an external app progamtically. Once again Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: @sgpalit Do I need to install any component or runtimes on WAS for executing this code ?

Comment: No, you need to setup on client side. IBM JDK comes with development environment like RAD and you also need to setup the server too. after it you can copy paste the directory to other machine where your program needs to work.

Comment: Hi @Apocalyp5e, did you get anywhere with this, I also have a requirement to "create something similar as Web-sphere's web console" for WAS 7 and 8.5. Ideally I was hoping to find some IBM WAS REST/SOAP Admin API which I could  invoke from an application (not necessarily written in Java) running on another host and inspect/query the state of the WAS server. Unfortunately it looks like I might need to write a java application which uses this IBM WAS management Jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems my problem was with adminClient.invoke method I wasn't passing parameters correctly. It got fixed after having correct parameters. I hope this helps if someone is having same problem.